# Is there a right way to change a non umbrella project to use umbrella feature with Phoenix framework?

Tags: phoenix-framework, umbrella

Using Phoenix framework now. At the beginning, we didn't use `--umbrella` option to generate the project. So the structure is like a simple app of umbrella way.

Now want to change the project to the `umbrella` way. Is it possible and how to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of phoenix 1.3 and elixir 1.5:

Generate a fresh umbrella app in a separate directory:

```
$ mix new my_umbrella --umbrella
```

Move your phoenix application to the `apps/` directory in the new umbrella directory:

```
$ mv /path/to/my_app /path/to/my_umbrella/apps/
```

Your build path, deps folder, and main config and mix files now live in the root of the umbrella. You'll need to add the following lines to your `project` function in your phoenix `mix.exs` to point to the right locations as below:

```
# my_umbrella/apps/my_app/mix.exs

def project do
  [
    # ...

    build_path: "../../_build",
    config_path: "../../config/config.exs",
    deps_path: "../../deps",
    lockfile: "../../mix.lock",

    # ...
  ]
end
```

Refetch your dependencies from the root of the umbrella.

```
$ mix deps.get
```

Assuming you're using brunch, you'll also need to edit the `assets/package.json` file in your phoenix app folder to point to the correct location for `deps/`:

```
// my_umbrella/apps/my_app/assets/package.json
"phoenix": "file:../../../deps/phoenix",
"phoenix_html": "file:../../../deps/phoenix_html"
```

You may need to refresh the `package-lock.json` file to re-run `npm install` command if using a recent version of `npm`.

From the root of the umbrella, you should be able to start your phoenix server.

```
$ mix phx.server
```

Comment: Very detailed guide. Thank you!